# Emberjs and jQuery UI integration questions

Tags: jquery-ui, ember.js, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to understand how the integration between jQueryUI and Emberjs should be done. I am new to both libs and to javascript so this might be a newbie question.
I have this jsfiddle set up: http://jsfiddle.net/pSKgV/1/ and it renders this resulting document:

```
<body class="ember-application">  
    <div id="ember129" class="ember-view">  
        <div id="ember163" class="ember-view ui-draggable"></div>  
    </div>  
</body>
```

The code is mostly taken from this blog post: http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/03/10/using-ember-js-with-jquery-ui/

Questions: How do I put something inside the inner div? I want to put some content that i can bind to something.
I have tried the following:
`{{view App.Draggable}}Drag Me{{/view}}` but that gives an error. I’ve also tried
adding this to the App.Draggable object:

```
didInsertElement: function() {  
     this.$().html(“Drag Me”)  
     }
```

but that did not give the expected results. How is the best way to use/access the jquery/jqueryui functions such as `.html()` in this situation?
Also, is the outer div necessary or can I make this view only render one div element?

regards
Oskar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/XMgwV/

You forget the # symbol `{{#view App.Draggable}}Drag me{{/view}}`. You should also create namespaces in Ember using `Ember.Namespace.create()` instead of just using an empty `{}`

Comment: You should accept the answer so Roy gets his reputation :)

Also, a compelling reason for using Ember.Namespace is that debugging will be easier, as generic notation for object names will be replaced with prettified (MyNamespace.MyClass) strings in debugging output. Handy!

Comment: pardon my manners, the answer is now accepted! I can also add the answer to my follow up questions. The outer div seems to be a placeholder from ember/handlebars. Other view elements ends up inside this div as well. Not sure it makes sense to access the .html method or other similar methods, it should probably be avoided